How to limit the number of initrd images kept in /boot under Debian Linux?
initramfs failed to do its job a few days ago and I've just noticed today that my boot partition was almost full because of useless initrd images. Is there a way of telling Debian to keep only two or three initrd images at most? I'm not sure that I have the same problem under Mobian which is derived from Debian. I'm under Debian 12 as far as I know.

Does the number of initrd images not match the number of kernels on your system? Usually they are 1:1 and you remove kernels when unused. Typically you keep at most 3 kernels (latest, latest-1, currently running)

You're right. I think that I've found the problem, the obsolete kernels aren't removed in the graphical user interface whereas using apt in command line suggests me to run apt autoremove and then the obsolete kernels are correctly uninstalled with their corresponding initrd images.
